# Android facebook sdk login issue for second time

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I have hash key of my signing certificate, I got using keytool as below :

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
base64
```

I have successfully generated key and I have add that key to my Facebook developer page.

When i run my app for first time, then it will works fine but when i try again after logout and login again, it shows error message - `this app has no android key hashes configured`

i have also tried the below code:

```
   try {
       PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
               "com.example.mypack", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
       for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
           MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
           md.update(signature.toByteArray());
           Log.i("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
           }
   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
   }
```

But still its not working. Same problem happens with Facebook hello sample app. How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In new Facebook SDK you can configure hash-keys of your application in **MyApps/YourAppName/Settings** :

[image]

But i also stack with problem of hashkeys.

When we configure application the first time, you can specify two hashkeys :

- Development Key
- Release Key

[image]

I think Facebook missed this option in settings.

### How you can specify keys?

1) Open Settings of your Application and click on Getting Started

[image]

2) Select Android

[image]

3) Scroll to bottom and click Next

[image]

4) Change keys for development\release version.

> Note. In my case i specify same keys for both version. This is not good way.

Comment: and when i generate a new Release Key Hash then it also show same  Development Key Hashes.

Comment: @siddharth did you change your application in Release mode?

Comment: No. how can i do that?

Comment: @siddharth in **Status & Review** section. You can find a switch in top of page.

Comment: but still i get same hash key.